# 2-morphism between circuits in a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, 2-categories

We are used to seeing equations between circuits in monoidal categories like this:

[image: A string diagram equation]

I am wondering about morphisms between string diagrams.  I think they are 2-cells.  I have an example of a 2-cell here, but it is for just a standard composition of morphisms.

[image: a 2-morphism between compositions]

What I am wondering about is 2-cells between arbitrary string diagrams in a monoidal category.  Are there examples?  Is it modelled with surface diagrams?  Can FD-Hilb be seen as a 2-category, and if so, what are the 2-cells?

Comment: Do you want to define morphisms between diagrams of the *same shape*?

Comment: @Berci thank you for your question!  I am very new to this, so I was not aware that I had to be specific like that.  I don't want to have to make restrictions like that.